# How to reprogram electronics microchips?

Tags: gps, microchip, hardware

I recently have bought a GPS tracker, and it comes with the option of cutting of your engine by reducing the flow of oil to the engine. I want to know if its possible to access the programming/code used in this microprocessor, or in any microprocessor in any electronic. For instance if i want to know hoy my t.v remote control was programmed, could i access its microprocessor and see how did they program it? Although my main concern is with the GPS tracker, and they way its programmed. Also, can i reprogram it? Is this possible? if not, can i still see hoy did they programmed it. How can i do this??

I really have no idea in this topic, thanks for the help.

Comment: start by reading and looking up the part number off of the part(s) in question.  they may be custom for that product vendor.  with or without the part number it might be impossible to read and/or reprogram the part.

Comment: Reverse engineering native code requires some skill, and quite some persistence.

Comment: It's often possible to reprogram a MCU if you know its part number, and you possibly make a rig in order to be connected to its pins (assuming it is an inline programmable MCU). However, usually for those kind of chips, there are code protection flags that forbid you to read the firmware directly. However you can always attempt to reverse the bus communication using a logic analyzer, and then implement your own code base for the appropriate target that emulates that bus functionality.